# How to use numpy.savez to save array with subarrays into separate .npy files

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have just recently started using numpy and was wondering some things.
I have a numpy array that looks like this after splitting it:

```
[array([1,2,3]),
array([4,5,6])]
```

I want to use numpy.savez to save the main array into the .npz archive with each subarray in its own .npy file.

I thought using this:

```
numpy.savez('dataFile', mainArray)
```

would work but it only creates the archive with a single .npy file called arr_0.npy.

Is there a way to do something like this? and if so is there a way so that I can use any array with any number of subarrays with that method. To get these arrays I am reading from a .bin file that could contain any number of elements that would split into any number of arrays. This is why I'm having a hard time.

Is there a way to add files to an already created .npz file?

Comment: any help would be appreciated, even to tell me if my question was poorly written.

Answer (score 5):

After doing more research I came upon the answer to my main question. I found out that you can use the *arg to loop through the list of arrays to add them.

I changed the code to

```
numpy.savez('test', *[mainArray[x] for x in rang(len(mainArray))])
```

This gave me the solution i was looking for. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think this is equivalent to `numpy.savez('test', *mainArray)`

Comment: what does the '*' do?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save the subarrays in your main array, then you probably need to use `save` manually, i.e.

```
mainArray = [np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([4,5,6])]
for i in range(len(mainArray)):
    np.save('dataFile_%i'%i, mainArray[i] )
```

Or you can use `savez` to save subarrays separately and load them later.

```
mainArray = [np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([4,5,6])]
np.savez('dataFile', mainArray[0], mainArray[1])

npzfile = np.load('dataFile.npz')
npzfile['arr_0']
npzfile['arr_1']
```

Comment: if i used the save manually can I put those individual files into a single .npz archive?